# Use wildcard ID with jQuery and get wildcard ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, wildcard

I have 4 IDs

```
hideshow1
hideshow2
hideshow3
hideshow4
```

Now when the buttons of those IDs are clicked I want to preform individual actions using those integers on the end.  So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=hideshow]").click(function() {

  });
});
```

Which is enough to act on the click for each of those buttons, but I need to extract the integer on the end to use it to only act on the one that was clicked. Example if #hideshow1 is clicked

```
$('#hideshow%').html('Hide');
$('.success%').addClass('test');
```

Where the % is where the integer would be extracted from the initial hideshow ID.

Comment: Play with substring (or similar) on the `$(this).attr("id")`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always try to extract the id/index like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=hideshow]").click(function() {
      var index = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace('hideshow',''), 10);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/b3Wvt/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=hideshow]").click(function() {
      var matches = this.id.match(/\d+$/);
       alert(parseInt(matches[0]));
  });
});
```

Comment: @BobbyS - Does this answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` to get the number from the `id`. If you remove the hideshow string from the `id` then you will left with the number at the end of `id`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=hideshow]").click(function() {
       num = this.id.replace('hideshow','');
  });
});
```