# Wildcard digit with jQuery in form ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code (abbreviated) that renders from the Gravity Forms WordPress plugin with no hooks or other means of altering its output (other than forking the plugin):

```
<div class="gform_heading">...</div>
<form id="gform_8" action="/volunteer/">
    <div class="gform_body gform-body">...</div>
    <div class="gform_footer top_label">...</div>
</form
```

I need for the `div class="gform_heading">...</div>` to be a child of the `<form>` element:

```
<form id="gform_8" action="/volunteer/">
    <div class="gform_heading">...</div>
    <div class="gform_body gform-body">...</div>
    <div class="gform_footer top_label">...</div>
</form
```

I'm planning to use this jQuery to alter the DOM.

`$(".gform_heading").prependTo("[id^=gform_]");`

However, the site has multiple forms and the `gform_...` id has a number after the underscore that changes depending on the form rendered to the page. I need to wildcard the number in the jQuery so it can work for any form, present or future, that the site may embed into a page.

I tried the solution at [Use wildcard ID with jQuery and get wildcard ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991010/use-wildcard-id-with-jquery-and-get-wildcard-id/20991132) in my Inspector console (substituting my form ID and class names) but it didn't work.

What would be the most correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Does it not select the element properly, or does it not prepend properly?

Comment: Have you tried just `$(".gform_heading").prependTo('form')`?

Comment: @skara9 Meaning, it didn't do anything at all. Not sure why. I'm not well-versed in jQuery.

Comment: @justinas Good point. My question is, what if there's more than one form on the page? Wouldn't it prepend to all the forms?

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the forms on the page, check for matches on the id and the class on the preceding element before you prepend...

```js
$('form').each(function(i, o) {
  let before = $(o).prev();
  if (o.id.includes('gform_') && before.hasClass('gform_heading')) {
    before.prependTo($(o)).append(` - and my id if you need it is ${o.id.split('gform_')[1]}`) 
  }
})
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gform_heading">gform_heading</div>
<form id="gform_8" action="/volunteer/">
  <div class="gform_body gform-body">...</div>
  <div class="gform_footer top_label">...</div>
</form>


<div class="gform_heading">gform_heading</div>
<form id="other_8" action="/volunteer/">
  <div class="gform_body gform-body">...</div>
  <div class="gform_footer top_label">...</div>
</form>
```